# MongoDB как update-ить вложенные объекты?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

имеется структура БД:

```
todolists[
      {
       name: "Books",
       id: ObjectID(заданный Mongo),
       needs:[
              {
               task: "Harry Potter1",
               isCompleted: false
              },
              {
              task: "Harry Potter2",
               isCompleted: true
              }
              ]
       },
       {
       name: "Places",
       id: ObjectID(заданный Mongo),
       needs:[
              {
               task: "Boodapesht",
               isCompleted: false
              },
              {
              task: "Varshava",
               isCompleted: true
              }
              ]
       }
```

И необходимо изменить у `task`-a с именем `"Varshava"`, в `todolist`-e с именем `"Places"` значение поля `isCompleted` на `false`.

Как до него так глубоко достучаться?
Следующим кодом добавлял необходимые `task` объекты в `todolists`. 
(Может, как-нибудь поможет)

```
db.get().collection('todolists').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectID(activeID)}, 
{ $push: {                                                                                     
    needs: {                                                                                  
      task: todo.task,                                                                                    
      isCompleted: todo.isCompleted                                                                                   
}                                                                               
}                                                                           
}, {new: true}
...
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
db.getCollection('/*имя коллекции */').update({_id: ObjectId("/* искомый id */"),   
 "needs" :{$elemMatch:{"task": "Varshava"}}},   
 {$set:{"needs.$.isCompleted":true}})
```